# Google Translate API Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, translate

I'm currently trying to implement the Google Translate API in my nodejs app. After a some trial and error (and googling) I finally figured out how to properly instantiate a new Translate object by passing in an object with a `projectId` and `credentials`.

However, my figuring out how to do this was mostly luck. Where would I actually find the documentation from google about what should go in this constructor? The closest I've found is [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/translate/latest/translate/v2.translate) that shows that the constructor takes a `TranslateConfig` but doesn't actually explain what the config is.

```js
const GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL);
async function translateText() {
  const translate = new Translate({projectId: GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL.project_id, credentials: GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL});
  let myTranslate = await translate.translate('who are you', 'es');
  console.log(myTranslate);
}
```

TLDR: Where do I find documentation that explains the valid arguments for this constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use search input at the top of the page you've referenced to gain access to the specification of what TranslateConfig is:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/translate/latest/translate/v2.translateconfig?hl=en

You can see there that by itself it exposes only `apiEndpoint`, `autoRetry`, `key` and `maxRetries` properties, but inherits a bunch of properties of the `GoogleAuthOptions` interface.

You can also check the the official Git repository - maybe it will be of more use to you:

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate